# How to import an image with the local path listed in a json file?

Tags: json

I am having a problem setting up a an image in json file with local path.
I have a folder named Images and a Data json file. I want to json file to hold my pictures in json locally.

```
{
        "name": "John",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "image": "./Images/picture1.jpg"
},
{
        "name": "John",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "image": "./Images/picture2.jpg"
},

{
        "name": "John",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "image": "./Images/picture1.jpg"
},
{
        "name": "John",
        "id": "001",
        "price": "$995",
        "image": "./Images/picture2.jpg"
},
```

Please tell my why this does not work.

Comment: I want to be more specified like why my "image" : "./Images/picture2.jpg" does not link to my Image folder in text editor ?

Comment: In the above scenario , append the image path to window.location.href .. just to make an url

Answer (score 0):

JSON files only contain strings without any linking. So `"./Images/picture2.jpg"` is just a string without any meaning for your editor.

Some apps or editors might present some eye candy features, like maybe what you are looking for. But this is totally an option of the editor and not something of JSON itself.

JSON are plain text files that store key, values.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for reply ajimix. However, when i use absolute path like "image" : "http://www.placekitten.com/100/200 work fine.

Comment: But that is a url, so as I said, your editor may have some feature to transform the urls to clickable links. But that is a feature of the editor. So based on what you say, that feature works for urls but not for local paths